# Enable and disable CKEditor Inline editing using Angular

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

How can I enable or disable ckeditor.inline on a div based on a click of a button/link.

This is how I would achieve it in jquery but can't figure it out using angular.

```
$('.toggle-edit').click(function(e){ 
  var id_editedDiv = $(this).data('editTarget');
  var editedDiv = '#' + id_editedDiv;

  if( $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable') == 'true' )
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','false');
    CKEDITOR.instances.id_editedDiv.destroy();
    $(this).text('Start Editing');
  }
  else
  {
    $(editedDiv).attr('contenteditable','true');
    CKEDITOR.inline( id_editedDiv );
    $(this).text('Finish Editing');
  }
});
```

This is how I achieved the result.

https://plnkr.co/edit/YUOYGa?p=preview

But now I need to figure out how to bind the model to the CKEditor so that my changes are updated in the model when I hit save.

Answer (score 0):

You can use button with ng-click attribute for example:

```
<button type="button" class="inlineEditButton"
    ng-controller="CKEditorController"
    ng-click="changeInlineEditindState()"
</button>
```

in CKEditorController you should define method:

```
$scope.changeInlineEditindState = function() {
// your code
}
```

You can do something like:

```
var content = '';
```

After instances creation add listener:

```
ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ck.setData(content);
            });
```

On save button click:

```
content = ck.getData();
```

Comment: If you look at the https://plnkr.co/edit/YUOYGa?p=preview I figured out how to do it but am having issues with binding the content back to the model

Comment: i have changed your code little bit. Please see https://plnkr.co/edit/EHIpCw4ORLW6MzGOGCsa?p=preview
You just should get plain text if you need it

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I have done. I didn't think it was really using angular properly because my model is not being bound to the CKEditor and therefore not being updated using the angular framework. If you add a post with the solution I can then mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Destroys the editor instance, releasing all resources used by it. If the editor replaced an element, the element will be recovered.

In your controller:

```
alert( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 ); // e.g. object
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();
alert( CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 ); // undefined
```

[More detail](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy)

Comment: I know how to enable and disable CKEditor using the destroy. I am trying to implement it using AngularJS. So not using jQuery. The issue is that in my sample plnkr I don't know how to bind the model back on the save click